# Cannot import csv-parse on lambda in nodejs 12

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am writing a code which requires csv-parse on lambda.
Runtime is node 12.x.

I installed following modules via npm 6.14.10 (node v12.20.1)

```
{
  "name": "data_analysis_node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1282.0",
    "csv-parse": "^5.3.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security"
  }
}
```

Then I zipped a node_modules directory, upload it, attached it to a layer, applyed the layer to the function and wrote a following code.

index.js

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync'); 
const fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('fine')
};
```

but it has not been working and showing following errors.

```
2022-12-26T14:28:45.472Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {
"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError"
,"errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'csv-parse/lib/sync'\nRequire 
stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'csv-parse/lib/sync'","Require stack:","- /var/task/index.js","- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js","- 
/var/runtime/index.js","    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
```

I re-checked the inside the node_modules, and I confirmed the path to csv-parse is correct.

[image]

I also commented out the line imports csv-parse, and it didn't output any errors and seemed importing other modules fine.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
//const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync'); 
const fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('fine')
};
```

I have been stacked 3 to 4 hours, so any suggestion are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
const csvParse = require('csv-parse');
// do whatever with csvParse
```

It may be that there is a naming collision with the csv-parse API

### EDIT

According to the [docs](https://csv.js.org/parse/api/sync/) you need to require the parse module from `csv-parse/sync`, not `csv-parse/lib/sync`

The following should work:

```
const parse = require('csv-parse/sync');
```

I received the same error you did when requiring from `csv-parse/lib/sync` and it worked fine when required from `csv-parse/sync`

Answer (score 1):

When creating a Lambda layer for NodeJS, structure in your zip file should be `nodejs/node_modules/` and not just `node_modules/`
Optionally, for multiple versions, you can put `nodejs/nodeXY/node_modules/`
You can read more about Lambda layers in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried your suggestion but it did not fix the problem...